# Unable to deploy rails test app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm working through the odin project's web development course and I'm getting tripped up on the last part of the installations project where you are tasked with deploying a rails app to Heroku. I've been working on this for about a week but I refuse to give up but I realize that I need some help.

Here's the link to the tutorial I'm trying to work through (on a mac):

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app

I have a Heroku account set up, and am running Ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.5.1. Rubygems are at 2.6.1 (but I tried them at 2.5.1 too).

Everything works fine but when I get to `heroku run rake db:migrate` I always get the time out error:

```
[~/railsbridge/test_app] ruby-2.3.0 $ git push heroku master     
Everything up-to-date

[~/railsbridge/test_app] ruby-2.3.0 $ heroku run rake db:migrate 
Running rake db:migrate on powerful-journey-35824... up, run.9421
▸    ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000
```

I saw another post suggesting that the problem is a result of the connection I'm using blocking port `5000` (I'm at a library). I checked port `5000` on canyouseeme.org as well but it also timed out.

I then tried deploying the app detached using `heroku run:detached rake db:migrate` and it seems to work until I open heroku again and it shows that the page I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Basically what I'm asking is, does anyone have any idea why this test app isn't getting pushed from my terminal to the heroku deployment page?

Comment: Try running `heroku log` look at the last lines

Answer (score 0):

I'm a python/django guy, but taking a guess the "everything up to date" message is likely because you have not commited your changes to git.  Try:

```
git commit -a
git push heroku master
```

Now run your rake command.